# How do I get the String type or timestamp type by giving a year

Tags: java

there is a requirement to get the startTime and endTime around the whole year by giving a int year, for example, given a variable `int year = 2017`, I want to get the starttime `String "2017-01-01 00:00:00"` and endtime `String "2017-12-31 23:59:59"`, or get the starttime timestamp 1483200000 and endtime timestamp 1514735999. 2 results are ok to us, How should I do by java8 or below? I have known:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String datetime = sdf.format(new Date(*timestamp*))
```

but I have no idea how I can get the timestamp by the given year, please help to check

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Did you look at the java.time package?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-

Comment: Below Java 8, use the [ThreeTen backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

Comment: I have made up my question, can help to check it.

Comment: you can also modify `Calender` Instance of java

Comment: This code omits the last 60th second of the year, so this approach fails to account for the entire year. Better is the Half-Open approach commonly used in date-time handling, where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive.

Comment: You must be at offset +08:00? Judging by the Unix timestamps that you claim to be New Year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int year = 2017;

// Using LocalDateTime (Java 8+ or Java 6+ with ThreeTen backport)
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String start1 = LocalDateTime.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0).format(dtf);
String stop1 = LocalDateTime.of(year, Month.DECEMBER, 31, 23, 59, 59).format(dtf);
System.out.println(start1 + " - " + stop1);

// Using Calendar (antiquated)
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(year, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
String start2 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
cal.set(year, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31, 23, 59, 59);
String stop2 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(start2 + " - " + stop2);
```

*Output*

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-12-31 23:59:59
2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-12-31 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use a half-open interval

As Basil Bourque said in a comment: use a half-open interval. That is, define year 2017 as the time from the first moment of 2017 *inclusive* to the first moment of 2018 *exclusive*. So any moment that is on or after the start time and strictly before the end time belongs to the year.

Philosophical argument: It saves us from deciding whether to run up to the last second, the last millisecond or the last nanosecond of the year. An even if we rook the last nano, we would still have excluded a full nano from the year, which is incorrect. Yes, I know, your application only needs a granularity of seconds, so “it doesn’t matter”. But what if the next version does require a finer granularity? And even if it won’t, you should not want to fill errors or inaccuracies into your program, not even when the user doesn’t see any symptom of them.

Practical argument: A half-open interval simplifies some things, both when calculating the timestamps and when applying them.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");

    Year year = Year.of(2017);

    long startTime = year.atDay(1).atStartOfDay(zone).toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println(startTime);

    long endTime = year.plusYears(1).atDay(1).atStartOfDay(zone).toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println(endTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 1483200000
> 1514736000
> ```

If you absolutely insist, you may of course subtract 1 from the latter number.

Notice that using `atStartOfDay()` also saves us from assuming that the day begins at 00:00:00 and ends a second after 23:59:59. Funny time anomalies may cause this not to be the case. Such anomalies are in the time zone database and Java takes them into account when we just query the start of day in a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using `java.sql.Timestamp`

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

       Date date= new Date();

       long time = date.getTime();
       System.out.println("Time (Milliseconds): " + time);

       Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
       System.out.println("Current Time Stamp: " + ts);
    }
}
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 only:

```
int year = 2017;

// using one of the predefined format from enum java.time.format.FormatStyle
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG);

LocalDateTime beginDate = LocalDateTime.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.of(year, Month.DECEMBER, 31, 23, 59, 59);

String beginDateFormatted = beginDate.format(formatter);
String endDateFormatted = endDate.format(formatter);

long beginTimestamp = this.beginDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
long endTimestamp = this.endDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
```

Check working example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BJejwIo6r).

Comment: This code assumes the year starts at 00:00:00.0. That may not always be true in all places in all years. And this code also assumes every year ever where ends at 23:59:59 which also may not always be true.